# pickerViews crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, uipickerview

Here is my code:

```
@synthesize pickerLetter, pickerNumber, pickerSymbol;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 letters = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", nil];
 numbers = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
 symbols = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"+", @"-", @"/", nil];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
 return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 if (pickerView == pickerLetter) {
    return letters.count;
 } else if (pickerView == pickerNumber){
    return numbers.count;
 } else {
    return symbols.count;
 }
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 if (pickerView == pickerLetter) {
    return [letters objectAtIndex:row];
 } else if (pickerView == pickerNumber){
    return [numbers objectAtIndex:row];
 } else {
    return [symbols objectAtIndex:row];
 }
}
```

This is giving me

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

when I use the pickers in the Simulator.

The code that is causing the crash is

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",[letters objectAtIndex:[pickerLetter selectedRowInComponent:0]],[numbers objectAtIndex:[pickerNumber selectedRowInComponent:1]],[symbols objectAtIndex:[pickerSymbol selectedRowInComponent:2]]];
}
```

Comment: Which line of code exactly is causing the exception?

Comment: it is crashing everytime I move the pickers to another element of the arrays

Comment: if I don't play with the pickers, it works and they are shown properly

Comment: Update your question with the actual code causing the crash.

Comment: return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Comment: No, that's not where the app is crashing. Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash. And posting a comment is not updating your question.

Comment: @rmaddy I posted all my code if it can help. I'm also going to try to post the crash causes.

Comment: How are your pickers arranged? Are there 3 different picker views in a single screen or do you bring up only one based on a button click or some user action?

Comment: @rmaddy I followed the instructions and I could understand where the error was. thank you very much!

Comment: FYI - based on the fact that you are calling `@synthesize`, you need to find a modern tutorial. The use of `@synthesize` in most cases hasn't been needs for a few years now. This is unrelated to your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've narrowed down your issue to this code:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",[letters objectAtIndex:[pickerLetter selectedRowInComponent:0]],[numbers objectAtIndex:[pickerNumber selectedRowInComponent:1]],[symbols objectAtIndex:[pickerSymbol selectedRowInComponent:2]]];
}
```

But this line has several calls to `objectAtIndex:` so it's hard to know the exact issues. Plus this code is hard to read and impossible to debug. Start by splitting up this code as follows:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSInteger letterIndex = [pickerLetter selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSString *letter = letters[letterIndex];
    NSInteger numberIndex = [pickerNumber selectedRowInComponent:1];
    NSString *number = numbers[numberIndex];
    NSInteger symbolIndex = [pickerSymbol selectedRowInComponent:2];
    NSString *symbol = symbols[symbolIndex];

    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", letter, number, symbol];
}
```

Doing this you will be able to narrow down the real cause of your issue.

As you can see, the problem is that you are referencing the wrong component number from the `pickerNumber` and `pickerSymbol`. All three pickers only have 1 component so you need to select component `0` from all three pickers.

The needed code is:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSInteger letterIndex = [pickerLetter selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSString *letter = letters[letterIndex];
    NSInteger numberIndex = [pickerNumber selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSString *number = numbers[numberIndex];
    NSInteger symbolIndex = [pickerSymbol selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSString *symbol = symbols[symbolIndex];

    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", letter, number, symbol];
}
```

Avoid putting more than one or two method calls on a single line of code. It makes the code less readable and much harder to debug if there is a problem.

Answer (score -1):

you are calling a wrong way to implement the method

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 if (pickerView == pickerLetter) {
    return [letters objectAtIndex:row];
 } else if (pickerView == pickerNumber){
    return [numbers objectAtIndex:row];
 } else {
    return [symbols objectAtIndex:row];
 }
}
```

change it to

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 if (component == 0) {
    return [letters objectAtIndex:row];
 } else if (component == 1){
    return [numbers objectAtIndex:row];
 } else {
    return [symbols objectAtIndex:row];
 }
}
```

Comment: No, this is not correct. The OP's code is correct for these methods. The OP has 3 separate picker views with one component each.